# How do I use FRIEND_TEST with TYPED_TEST in Google Test?

Tags: c++, googletest

In Google Test, I know how to use FRIEND_TEST.

And I know how to use TYPED_TEST.

But how do you make a TYPED_TEST also be a FRIEND_TEST?

Answer (score 2):

Adding `template <typename T>` in front of the `FRIEND_TEST` declaration worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this example:

```
namespace Test
{
     template<typename ClassA>
      class TestClassA;

    template<typename Class>
    class GTEST_TEST_CLASS_NAME_(TestClassA, TestMethodOne);
    template<typename Class>
    class GTEST_TEST_CLASS_NAME_(TestClassA, TestMethodTwo);
}
```

Now, you need to define a `macro` for the test friend like this:

```
#define CLASS_A_TEST_FRIENDS                   \                                                                    
template<typename ObjectLocator>               \
friend class ::Test::TestClassA;               \
FRIEND_TEST(::Test::TestClassA, TestMethodOne); \
FRIEND_TEST(::Test::TestClassA, TestMethodTwo);
```

And then continue your work with the typed test.